# Angular9:core.js:6228 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Can't resolve all parameters for Subscription: (?)

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

I'm a newbie and learning Angular.

I want to pass data between two components (not a parent-child component). I write a service.ts file to achieve it then met this error. I have found a lot in Stackoverflow, but seems no effects.

I don't know what went wrong, so I will put all the code out.

Below is the code.

By the way, how to solve "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."?

```
//service
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TransfermessageService {
  public receiveMsg:any;
  constructor() { }

  public subject = new Subject<any>();
    sendMessage(message: any) {
        this.subject.next({ text: message });
    }
    clearMessage() {
        this.subject.next();
    }
    getMessage(): Observable<any> {
        return this.subject.asObservable();
    }
}
```

```
//component 1
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {RequestService} from '../../../services/request/request.service';
import {Router,NavigationStart, GuardsCheckEnd,ResolveStart,NavigationError, Event as NavigationEvent } from '@angular/router';
import {TransfermessageService} from '../../../services/common/transfermessage/transfermessage.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-login-session-code',
  templateUrl: './login-session-code.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login-session-code.component.scss'],
})

export class LoginSessionCodeComponent implements OnInit {
  public riskRole: string = localStorage.getItem('userRole');
  public sessioncode: any;
  public token_user: any;


  constructor(
    public RS: RequestService, 
    public router: Router,
    public TMS: TransfermessageService,

  ) {

  }

  ngOnInit(){

  }
  checkInputCall(){
    const api = this.RS.baseURL+ '/login/checkInput';
    const token_api= this.RS.baseURL+ '/login/checkToken';
    const parameters:object = {
        "email": localStorage.getItem('email'),
        "input": this.sessioncode,
        "type": localStorage.getItem('type')
    }
    this.RS.checkInput(api,parameters).subscribe(res => {
      if(res['data'].input_check) {
          localStorage.setItem('checkInput', JSON.stringify(res['data']));
          this.RS.checkToken(token_api,{"token": res['data'].user.token}).subscribe(res => {
            this.token_user = res;
            this.TMS.sendMessage({"ss": "ssss"});
            this.router.navigate(['/home']);
            // console.log(res); //return token_user
          })
      }else {
        alert("session code is not true");
      }
    })
  }

  ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
    this.router.events.subscribe((event: NavigationEvent) => {
      if(event instanceof NavigationStart) {
           console.log(event);
        }
    });
    this.router.events.subscribe((event: NavigationEvent) => {
      if(event instanceof GuardsCheckEnd) {
           console.log(event,'GuardsCheckEnd');
        }
    });
    this.router.events.subscribe((event: NavigationEvent) => {
      if(event instanceof NavigationError) {
           console.log(event,'NavigationError');
        }
    });
  }
}
```

```
//components 2
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import {TransfermessageService} from '../../services/common/transfermessage/transfermessage.service';
import {Subscription} from 'rxjs';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss'],
  providers: [TransfermessageService]
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  public ctrlHomeDetailTag: boolean = true;
  public ctrlHomeBasicTag: boolean = true;
  public ctrlTags: boolean = true;
  public receiveMsg: any;

  constructor(
    public router: Router,
    public TMS: TransfermessageService,
    public Subscription: Subscription
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('home page');
    const receiveMsg = this.TMS.getMessage();
    console.log(receiveMsg,'parameters');
  }
//  ngAfterViewInit():void {
//    this.Subscription = this.TMS.getMessage().subscribe(message => {
//      this.receiveMsg = JSON.parse(message);
//   console.log('this.receiveMsg', this.receiveMsg);
// })
//}
  ngonChanges() {

  }
  ngDoCheck() {

  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    // this.Subscription.unsubscribe();
   }
}
```

Comment: For second question: *how to solve 'It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.'?*, just add some problem description above the code.

Comment: hhh,im just kidding.

Comment: please post whatever solution you have found as an answer.

Comment: it is solved.it is nothing wo do with code i paste it out.autually, i found i import "import {Subscription} from 'rxjs' "in module.ts file.it is wriong,detele this wrong import and then it will work.